# How do I make the white part disappear?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two wheels (sprites) each with a loader which when rotated the white part shows up.
The loader is centered inside the Sprite and I am trying to make the white part disappear.

[image]

Any ideas?

Any pointers, would really appreciate it as still fairly new to actionscript 3.

```
  //create the first wheel
  backgroundURL = new URLRequest();
  backgroundLoader = new Loader();
  myWheelSprite = new Sprite();
  backgroundURL.url = "images/wheelimage.jpg";
  backgroundLoader.load(backgroundURL);

  //Use contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener to find out the image width and height.
  backgroundLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,backgroundLoaderimageFinishedLoading);
  myWheelSprite.x = 60;
  myWheelSprite.y = 60;
  myWheelSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myMouseClickFunction);
  trace("myWheelSprite X = "+myWheelSprite.x);

  //create the second wheel
  backgroundURL2 = new URLRequest();
  backgroundLoader2 = new Loader();
  myWheelSprite2 = new Sprite();
  backgroundURL2.url = "images/wheelimage.jpg";
  backgroundLoader2.load(backgroundURL);

  //Use contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener to find out the image width and height.   backgroundLoader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,backgroundLoader2imageFinishedLoading);
  myWheelSprite2.x =480;
  myWheelSprite2.y = 480;
  trace("myWheelSprite2 X = "+myWheelSprite2.x);

//My code to rotate the image.

function myMouseClickFunction(event:MouseEvent) {
  var myTimeline:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({repeat:10});
  myTimeline.append(TweenLite.to(myWheelSprite, 10, {rotation:360, ease:Linear.easeNone}));  
    }
```

Comment: The white part...? A screenshot would be great.

Comment: you really found the most annoying image share site possible, uploaded the image to stackoverflow instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is the white background of the leftmost image overlapping the right one.

The best solution here is to use an image format that supports transparency, in your case PNG is probably the best.

Use something like photoshop to remove the white parts and save the image again, Flash will respect the transparency and everything will look good.

Answer (score 0):

".jpg" is your problem. JPG format does not support transparency. PNG does however.